# Directions of Lorenz's force

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm doing the following problem:

In an inclined plane with angle $θ=\frac{π}{6}$  two parallel rails are placed, $l=10$ $cm$,  of negligible electrical resistance and electrically connected to each other at the top. A conducting bar of mass $m=10$ can slide over them without friction
g and electrical resistance $R=0.1Ω$
. Everything is immersed in a uniform and constant magnetic field, directed vertically, of modulus $B=0.5$
T. At a certain moment the bar is left free to slide along the inclined plane.

I found the induced current $ i = \frac{lBcosθv}{R}$ that circulates in anticlockwise.

I don't understand the direction of Lorentz's force:

$F = il$ x $ B = \frac{l^2B^2}{R}cosθv$.

I have to calculate the coordinate  $ x $ of this force to apply Newton's theorem in order to find $v
$

Comment: *. . . directed vertically . . .* up or down?  *. . . circulates in anticlockwise . . .* looking from top ot bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, the force on the bar is a *motor effect* force, though it does arise from magnetic Lorentz forces on the moving charges inside it.

The direction of the force is found from Fleming's left hand motor rule (which you may need to look up). It is at right angles both to the bar and to the magnetic field. It's up to you to apply this to your problem.

Alternatively, you can apply the magnetic Lorentz force formula, $\vec F=q\ \vec v \times \vec B$ to the charge carriers in the bar. It gives the same result for the direction of the force on the bar, but you need to be careful with the direction of $\vec v$ and the sign of $q$ if the charge carriers are free electrons.

Comment: I know the right hand rule and I know I have to use it but I have difficulty applying it in this case

Comment: (a) I recommended that you use Fleming's left hand motor rule. Have you looked it up? It may be easier to use than the Lorentz force law. (b) What's difficult about your case? You know both the current direction and the magnetic field direction. The motor effect force is at right angles to both of these. (c) As you know, this site doesn't give answers to homework-type questions, but you may sometimes get help if your difficulties are conceptual **and you explain exactly what is troubling you**.